# Racket, execute arbitrary function with arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I would like to define a general function along the lines of:

```
(define (gen-func other-func)
   (other-func))
```

that will execute the function passed to it.  But, I want to be able to pass parameters with `other-func`.
So if I had:

```
(define (add-test a b c d)
    (+ a b c d))
```

and

```
(define (divide-test a b)
    (/ a b))
```

then I could do

```
(gen-func divide-test 3 4)
```

and

```
(gen-func add-test 1 2 3 4)
```

but it would actually do what I want (which is execute the function with passing along the arbitrary number of arguments).  This is part of my process of learning Racket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `apply` and rest arguments:

```
(define (gen-func func . args)
   (apply func args))
```

The dotted parameter list `func . args` results in all args after the first one being collected into the list `args`.  The reason that this works is that `(func . args)` is the same as `(cons func args)`, so when the function is called, `func` is set to `(car arglist)`, and `args` are set to `(cdr arglist)` which is the list of arguments after the first one.

Comment: Thanks alot!  Incidentally, do you know of any good repositories to find sample Racket code that does interesting things?  I know HTDP and the documentation are pretty darn good, but I'm trying to get a handle on macros.  Seeing actual usage examples (where the macro solves a real problem) would be very helpful

Comment: @NickO Unfortunately, I don't have any recommendation for Racket code repositories.  By the way, speaking of macros: `apply`, that was the answer to your original question is an ordinary function/procedure.

Comment: @NickO The third-party libraries on Planet have source: http://planet.racket-lang.org/. Also I suppose you could try browsing Racket projects on GitHub: https://github.com/languages/Racket

Comment: Rosetta Code may also be a helpful repository.  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Racket